# how to run only one test in sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt

sbt "project camera-answer" testOnly com.camera.parser.UtilTest

I run the test above. But it does no bussiness, it also runs all the tests.

How can I run one test only in sbt?

Answer (score 6):

To use from the command line, individual commands must be in quotes, like you did for `project camera-answer`:

```
$ sbt "project camera-answer" "testOnly com.camera.parser.UtilTest"
```

Comment: quotes for some reason are the way to go!